# What does the '$' in CSS mean?

Tags: html, css

I saw an animated project with a bunch of '$' in it. I have no idea what dollar signs are used for in CSS. I'm guessing it is for animations. Here is a sample of some of the code I was looking at:

```
$emoji-base-color: #FFDA6A;
$emoji-like-color: #548DFF;

.emoji--like {
background: $emoji-like-color;
 &:after {
            content: 'Like';
         }
```

Here's a link to the entire project: https://codepen.io/AshBardhan/pen/dNKwXz

Comment: That's SCSS, not CSS.

Comment: Those are SCSS variables and not default CSS behavior.

Comment: This is a SCSS variable. You can learn about SCSS here: http://sass-lang.com/.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Those are SASS (SCSS) variables which store color properties so they can be used later on. Also, to give you a basic concept, SASS is a CSS pre-processor which allows you to nest selectors, use mixins, store values on variables, etc.

You can see it (scss) referenced in the codepen CSS section:
[image]

Taken from [**SASS docs**](http://sass-lang.com/guide) (refer to variables):

> Think of variables as a way to store information that you want to
>   reuse throughout your stylesheet. You can store things like colors,
>   font stacks, or any CSS value you think you'll want to reuse. Sass
>   uses the $ symbol to make something a variable. Here's an example:

```
$font-stack: Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

If you are wondering the difference between SASS and SCSS, its basically syntax, below taken [from docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#syntax):

> There are two syntaxes available for Sass. The first, known as **SCSS**
>   (Sassy CSS) and used throughout this reference, is an extension of the
>   syntax of CSS. This means that every valid CSS stylesheet is a valid
>   SCSS file with the same meaning. This syntax is enhanced with the Sass
>   features described below. Files using this syntax have the .scss
>   extension.
>
> The second and older syntax, known as the indented syntax (or
>   sometimes just “**Sass**”), provides a more concise way of writing CSS. It
>   uses indentation rather than brackets to indicate nesting of
>   selectors, and newlines rather than semicolons to separate properties.
>   Files using this syntax have the .sass extension.

Answer (score 5):

`$` initiates a variable in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) which is a language extension that compiles to CSS (Similar to how CoffeeScript compiles to JavaScript) since CSS does not feature variables on its own.

Comment: CSS does feature variables on its own, but with a very different syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp.

Comment: Does it compile to CSS in the user´s browser or does the webserver compile? That is to say, is the requirements for this to work on the user side or server side?